# zmq between OS X and Win7 over LAN

Tags: python, zeromq

I'm attempting to use ZMQ to communicate between an OS X and Windows box on a LAN network. I've given both machines a fixed IP, and I can see the traffic coming through over wireshark. For some reason - that I hope we can get sorted out - I cannot pick up the packets on the receiving end. This code works fine for communication between two processes on the same machine.

On the client side (OS X):

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://204.102.224.2:5000")

for i in range(5):
    msg = "msg_{}".format(i)
    socket.send(msg)
    print "Sending", msg
    msg_in = socket.recv()
```

On the 'server' side (WIN 7):

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")

while True:
    msg = socket.recv()
    print "Got", msg
    socket.send(msg)
```

Not that I've also tried using the ip address assigned to the server machine when connecting, i.e. `"tcp://204.102.224.2:5000"`. Where am I going wrong with this? Are there some hidden configurations I need to deal with on the windows side? Out of curiosity, I tried going the other way, with windows on the sending side, and OS X on the receiving end and it worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your Windows firewall allows traffic on port 5000? You'll still see packets in Wireshark even if the Windows firewall is dropping them. Do you see any ACK from the SYN?

Comment: Whats the best way for me to find this out? I haven't been on windows since middle school, and I wasn't doing much with sockets then :) From what I can see in the capture, there is no ACK, just a bunch of TCP retransmissions.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7

Comment: will check it out, and report back